# problem to validate schema with "#number" to a real number

Tags: karate

problem:

$ | not equal | match failed for name: 'httpCode' (MAP:MAP)

$.httpCode | data types don't match (STRING:NUMBER)
'#number'
206

schema:

- def SchemaAccountProducts =
  """
  {
  "httpCode": "#number",
  "httpMessage": "#string",
  "timestamp": "#string",
  "moreInformation": "#string",
  "userFriendlyError": "#string",
  "response": {
  "cardList": "#(SchemaCardList)",
  "accountList": "#(SchemaAccountList)",
  "creditList": "#(SchemaCreditList)"
  }
  }
  """

response

{"httpCode":206,"httpMessage":"PARTIAL_CONTENT",

how to validate schema with "#number"??

Answer (score 1):

It is clear from the error message that the `206` in your actual response JSON is a string, not a number. If you are right, there is a serious bug in Karate, so please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

More likely though, your question is incomplete.

To prove Karate behavior, try this simple test:

```
* def response = { httpCode: 206 }
* match response == { httpCode: '#number' }
```

You can change `206` to `'206'` and see the difference.